# Branch from Revision or HEAD? Which to choose

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'm not sure whether to branch from the default selected revision number or HEAD when doing a Tortoise Branch.  I already got latest and built.  Now just trying to figure out which is best to branch from in terms of repo number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are the only person committing to the project, use a specific revision.

If you use HEAD, you can't be sure which version you'll get. (Someone else could commit between the time you look at the code and determine that it's ready to branch, and the time you actually do the branch.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your code and the size of the team working on it.

The only reason I think you would want to branch from a revision is if you are unsure of the current state of of the HEAD, like if peers are working on the trunk.

Answer (score 0):

Asl long as the rev number in question is the rev targeted by `HEAD` i dont think it matters. But i could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the latest, then HEAD = default selected revision number.

If not, then HEAD > default selected revision number.

In either case, you should be aware of specifically which revision you are branching from and what changes have made it into that revision.  So this means you should usually use a specific revision number, unless you're the only committer and are therefore certain that nobody checked in changes after your last update.

This is probably why Tortoise defaults to a specific revision: to encourage this behavior.